# Magento 2.2.8 | setup:static-content:deploy gives errors | Cannot read contents from file jquery.fileupload-ui.css No such file or directory

Tags: magento2.2, error, static-content, static-content-deploy

I can't deploy static content on my production site. Running command:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`

Gives me following error:

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]   Cannot read
>   contents from file
>   "magento2/http/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/product/product.css"
>   Warning!file_get_contents(magento2/http/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/product/product.css):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

For some reason, when not specifying the locale, it went through fine.

What could be causing the problem?

**UPDATE:**

The file permission of the aforementioned file looks a bit weird?

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx xxx  113 May  8 15:08 product.css -> magento2/http/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/product/product.css
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Found out that this is a symlink that points to a file somewhere else on my server. These are the file permissions of the file where the symlink is pointing to:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 3863 May  7 06:35 product.css
```

Should I change these file permissions? If so, what would I changed them to to keep me site secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution by disabling the Symlinks.

Navigate to **Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Template Settings** and set “Allow Symlinks” to “No”.

Change Materialization Strategy in `magento_root/app/etc/di.xml`. Change this:

```
<virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

To:

```
<virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

Then remove the static files, flush cache and deploy static content:

From magento_root (Be careful not to remove the `.htaccess` files):

1. rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml pub/static/frontend && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 2):

That caused by permission.

1. You can upgrade and deploy again.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>       php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB

2. if it still error, pls run command on root:

> find app/code lib var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc (
>   -type d -or -type f ) -exec chmod g+w {} + && chmod o+rwx app/etc/env.php

After that, repeat step 1.

Comment: This is my production site, will this cause any downtime?

Comment: it may downtime about some minutes when running command. You can put site with maintainance mode.

Comment: +1 from me, I'll wait for a bit, maybe someone will have a solution that will involve no downtime :) If not, I'll try your solution.

Comment: Got bash syntax error when trying to complete step 2: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: I think your missing -f in the end , php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f

Comment: My mode is production so there is no need for the `-f` param

Comment: Thank you for your help, after all, I found a solution. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like permission issue for pub/static

So just give necessary permission for pub/static then run your command and of course static content deploy will create a down time as well.

As of now run the below command in your root

> chmod -R 755 pub/static/

or

> chmod -R 777 pub/static/

**EDIT :**

Run the below command then deploy

> rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried that but with no luck :/

Comment: updated the answer @Greg

Comment: See my updated question, the file permission looks weird on that file... Or is it correct?

Comment: Ahh, just found that this is a symlink

Comment: Have a look at the updated question :)

Comment: chmod -R 644 product.css

Comment: That's what it is currently... I even tried 777 for testing purposes, but nothing that didn't work either :/

Comment: Thank you for your help, after all, I found a solution. Please see my answer.